# How do I create and use a Task in Verilog

Tags: arduino, verilog, quartus

I have recently been playing with the Arduino MKR Vidor 4000, and I have run into a small problem.
I want to be able to reuse code (like with a function in C++) and have the defined variables local to the piece of code, so they don't interact. I have come across Tasks in Verilog, and these seem to be the correct way of doing this.

The problem is, I can't get Quartus to compile it. It just reports an error:

> Error (12006): Node instance "comb_6" instantiates undefined entity
> "test". Ensure that required library paths are specified correctly, define the specified entity, or change the instantiation. If this entity represents Intel FPGA or third-party IP, generate the synthesis files for the IP.

Here is my code:

```
task automatic test(input [3:0] in, output [3:0] out);
   reg [3:0] temp;
   assign temp[0] = in[0];
   assign out[0] = temp[0];
endtask
test(bMKR_D[4:1], bMKR_D[8:5]);
```

This is included by a file which defines the available MKR Vidor pins.

Edit: Here is a minimal reproducible example... I think

```
module MKRVIDOR4000_top
(
  // Input definitions available for the MKR Vidor 4000
);
// Other signal declarations

// My code
task automatic test(input [3:0] in, output [3:0] out);
    reg [3:0] temp;
    assign temp[0] = in[0];
    assign out[0] = temp[0];
endtask
test(bMKR_D[4:1], bMKR_D[8:5]);

endmodule
```

From what I gather from the comments, I shouldn't be using any `assign`s inside a task. And I should also only call tasks from inside an `always`/`begin-end`/`initial` etc.
If I can't use tasks this way, what should I do to create reusable code in order to make basic logic gates, that can be synthesised? E.g a register bank

Comment: Use `assign` inside `module`, or use `begin-end` with `function`. Simple `function` can be synthesized, and doesn't add a hierarchy when you browse the design structure.

Comment: It looks like the error message is telling you that you are trying to call your task from outside a sequential block (`task` or `initial` or `always` or `final`). However, without a [mcve], it is not possible to tell. Please include one. And as others have said, don't use an `assign` statement in a task. It is legal but means something weird and, I think, is deprecated.

Comment: @toolic I am trying to use Verilog and the MKR Vidor to replicate basic logic gates in order to create a register bank.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor This is the case, I looked at where my files are included, and they are outside of any `always`, etc, blocks. I shall edit to include the file it is included into, but it is quite long as it has all the pin definitions usable with the MKR Vidor. Should I just add it here? Or put it in somewhere like paste bin?

Comment: A [mcve] is not _all_ your code. The idea is that you only include the relevant code. If I am right about the cause of your error, the IP is irrelevant. I can reproduce your error in 9 lines of code - https://www.edaplayground.com/x/ea72 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put the code I wanted to be able to reuse in a module, and it works okay now!
I am not sure if this is what I *should* be doing, so if anyone has a better way to do it, then I'm all ears!

I have, effectively, done this:

```
module test (input [3:0] in, output [3:0] out);
reg [3:0] temp;
assign temp[0] = in[0];
assign out[0] = temp[0];
endmodule

module main;
reg [7:0] bMKR_D;
test test1 (bMKR_D[4:1], bMKR_D[8:5]);
endmodule
```